# Cannot find template url in django

Tags: python, django

I have this project structure,

```
foo_project
    - templates
         - base.html
         - photo_list.html
         - photo_create.html
    - foo_project
         - __init__.py
         - asgi.py
         - settings.py
         - urls.py
         - wsgi.py
    - apps
       - photo
           - __init__.py
           - admin.py
           - apps.py
           - models.py
           - tests.py
           - urls.py
           - views.py
```

In `apps.photo.views.py`,

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, CreateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from .models import Photo

class PhotoList(ListView):
    model = Photo
    template_name_suffix = '_list'

class PhotoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Photo
    field = ['title', 'body', 'created', 'image']
    template_name_suffix = '_create'
    success_url = '/
```

in `foo_project/settings.py`

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In `foo_project/urls.py`,

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('apps.photo.urls')),
]
```

`photo.urls`,

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path

from .views import PhotoList, PhotoCreate, PhotoDelete, PhotoDetail, PhotoUpdate

app_name = 'photo'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PhotoList.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('create/', PhotoCreate.as_view(), name='create'),
]
```

When I hit the `localhost:8000`, it cannot find my template `photo/photo_list.html`, but I don't see anything missing. Is it because I have subapp structure?
I am using these version, 
django=3.0.4
python=3.7.3

Comment: You need to add a directory under `templates` named `photo` and put the files in there.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Should I have to add a folder even though I set it its path in `settings.py`??

Comment: yes, because the template path is constructed by the code in the view. See http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_template_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is constructed as `(model_app)/(model_name)(suffix_name).html`. So for this view, it will be `photo/photo_list.html`. This thus means that under your `templates` directory, you need to add a directory with the name of the app, and put the template files in there. So the file tree should look like:

```
foo_project
    - templates
         - base.html
    - foo_project
         - __init__.py
         - asgi.py
         - settings.py
         - urls.py
         - wsgi.py
    - apps
       - photo
           - templates
               - photo
                   - photo_list.html
                   - photo_create.html
           - __init__.py
           - admin.py
           - apps.py
           - models.py
           - tests.py
           - urls.py
           - views.py
```

or you can add these under the `templates` directory of your project:

```
foo_project
    - templates
         - base.html
         - photo
             - photo_list.html
             - photo_create.html
    - foo_project
         - __init__.py
         - asgi.py
         - settings.py
         - urls.py
         - wsgi.py
    - apps
       - photo
           - __init__.py
           - admin.py
           - apps.py
           - models.py
           - tests.py
           - urls.py
           - views.py
```

Comment: I am doing your second structure. and thank you for your link in the comment! It is very helpful